# Remove character during preg_replace function

Tags: php, preg-replace, character

I need to extract some text from a string, then replace that text with a character removed in one instance and not in another. Hopefully this example will show you what I mean (this is what I have so far):

```
$commentEntry = "@Bob1990 I think you are wrong...";
$commentText = preg_replace("/(@[^\s]+)/", "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://www.youtube.com/comment_search?username=${1}$1\">$1</a>", $commentEntry);
```

I want the result to be:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/comment_search?username=Bob1990">@Bob1990</a> I think you are wrong...
```

But am getting:

```
 <a href="http://www.youtube.com/comment_search?username=@Bob1990">@Bob1990</a> I think you are wrong...
```

I have been working on this one problem for at least an hour and nearly given up hope, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

could try something like this

```
$commentText = preg_replace("/(@)([^\s]+)/", "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://www.youtube.com/comment_search?username=$2\">$1$2</a>", $commentEntry);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is adapt the capturing. Move the `@` out of the braces:

```
preg_replace("/@([^\s]+)/",
```

Then you can write your replacement string like

```
'<a href="...$1">@$1</a>'
```

Note how the first `$1` just reinserts the text, and the second `$1` is prefixed by a verbatim `@` to get it back in.

Answer (score 0):

You're capturing the `@` in your pattern, so it'll always be output when you use `$1`. Try this instead:

```
$commentText = 
  preg_replace(
    "/@([^\s]+)/", 
    "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://www.youtube.com/comment_search?username=$1\">@$1</a>", 
    $commentEntry
  );
```

The difference here is that the `@` is no longer captured as part of `$1` (i.e. it'll capture only Bob1990. Since it's a literal value, it doesn't need to be part of any pattern. Instead, I just changed it to output as a literal value in the element text, directly before the captured name. (i.e. it now does `<a>@$1</a>` rather than just `<a>$1</a>`).